# material-ui-next component is initialize as hidden

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have just upgraded from material-beta to the new material-ui-text rc1. It compiles and works fine expect the components is initialized with the css property visibility set to hidden via different css classes that is applied to the components. I tried both dialog component (as in the example below) and the popover component. Same result. Both are hidden at start up.

The dialog component have this class applied .MuiModal-hidden-224. Seems wrong to me that the component is initialzed as hidden. This is the HTML of the root of the modal:

```
<div class="MuiModal-root-223 MuiDialog-root-216 MuiModal-hidden-224" role="dialog">
```

This is the react code i'm using.

```
   import * as React from "react";
import "./SharingDialog.less";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

interface IProps {
    locked: boolean
}

interface IState {
    open: boolean;
    anchorEl: any;
}

export default class SharingDialog extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            anchorEl: null
        }
    }

    handleOpen = (event:any) => {
        this.setState({open: true, anchorEl: event.currentTarget});
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({open: false})
    }

    render() {
        const { locked } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="sharing-dialog">
                <Button>Test</Button>
                <button disabled={!locked} className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event) => this.handleOpen(event)}>Open modal</button>
                <Dialog
                open={this.state.open}>                    
                    <div className="sharing-dialog-component">
                        Testing
                    </div>

                </Dialog>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Why does the modal start up as hidden?

Comment: how about changing th default state of open to true !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. It appears updating to React 16.3.2 will fix the problem.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11414

Comment: Just to be more specific it is the NPM package react-dom that needs to be updated to version 6.3.x to fix the problem.